# How to Stop Down Arrow on Scroll Bar from going off screen on page resize with CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to add a box on a web page that stays on screen at all times.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="mySideBar"> <!-- Some text and other elements --> </div>
```

The styles being applied look like this:

```
.mySideBar { position: fixed; width: 20%; height: 80%; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

That works nicely until I re-size my window then the down button on the scroll bar disappears offscreen and underneath my footer.  The Footer HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="myFooter"> <!-- Some text and other elements --> </div>
```

The CSS looks like this:

```
.myFooter { position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 24px; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

I've tried playing with position relative and a few other things but I can't seem to get it right.  It needs to work in IE7 too unfortunately and I'm afraid I can only post obfuscated snippets that display my problem.  Is there something I've obviously missed?

Comment: If your footer has a fixed width (in px) and sidebar is fluid (in %), sidebar has to go under footer at one point. And I can't tell you why it's leaving the screen if you don't post your layout.

Comment: I'll try in local with firefox and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer myself after I went away and came back to it today.  Sorry I didn't get back to those that left comments but I couldn't get online.  If you use bottom with a value set to 24px, the height of the footer, the overflow scroll bar will stay put.